# Excel - Dynamic row reference based on the row I paste a formula into?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a simple, oft-used formula that I paste as plain text into spreadsheets I receive. It looks something like this:

```
=IF(D8="FOO", "BAR", "BAZ")
```

It looks in D8 for the word "FOO". If it finds it it will show "BAR". If it doesn't it will show "BAZ"

It works great. The problem is I have to paste this formula as plain text into many spreadsheets. It should ALWAYS look in column D for "FOO", however I don't always want it to look in row 8. I'd like it to look at whatever row I'm pasting it into.

For example, if I pasted the above formula into row 25, say, I would like it to automatically change to this:

```
=IF(D25="FOO", "BAR", "BAZ")
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=IF(INDIRECT("D"&ROW())="FOO","BAR","BAZ")
```

That should work.  INDIRECT isn't a very quick formula, so if you have a lot of them it could slow things down for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a lot of details [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/excel-lesson-16-basic.htm). You can make cells reference other cells based upon where they are. My link is basically a how to for cell references.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't clear (or I'm not reading the contents of your link clearly enough). I get the concept of absolute vs. relative references, but the linked article isn't valid if I paste the formula as plain-text into another spreadsheet, say. I'm wondering if it's possible to write a formula that uses an absolute column reference but a row reference that's relative to the row the formula is pasted into.

Comment: Before reading this comment, I would like to answer you `=IF($D8="FOO", "BAR", "BAZ")`. I guess it is better to update this requirement to the question.